# Slow start up time for C# MVC4 Solution

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just created a new C# ASP MVC4 solution. Nothing very different from what I have before. Inside the solution I have five projects and the code for four of these is the same as before.

In the past when I chose debug it would take a couple of minutes for the application to start. Now however it takes 4-5 times longer and it would seem like every one of the projects is building even if I have not made any changes to the project.

Is this normal behavior? Do projects normally build every time even if no changes are made?

Comment: Did you try to profile the application inside a profiler to see where the code takes long?

Comment: It's not the code that takes long. It seems to be the building of the code. I say this because during this time I see a lot of messages appearing at the bottom of the screen flash by. Think I see mention of build and the words assembly.

Comment: How about simply scrolling up the list and take a closer look of these "flashing-by elements"?

Comment: Sorry but which list? What I see are messages in the lower 5mm of the VS2010 next to Ready:

Comment: There is no [Output window](http://i.imgur.com/2FyGa.png) in your Visual Studio .NET?